# Docker - Exposing container directories to host directories without obscuring original contents

Tags: docker, mount, volumes

I am still relatively new to Docker, so I haven't quite figured out all the nuances yet, so forgive me if this has already been resolved elsewhere.

I would like to share files between the container and the host.
So far I have been using volumes, and mounting a specific host directory to a container directory - but this presents an issue in that, if the host directory is messed around with, these changes are also present in the container.

Another problem I am experiencing is that if the host directory is empty, and is mounted to a pre-existing directory on the container, then the contents of the directory are made invisible. I do understand that this behaviour is consistent with mounting, so I know this is not technically an issue.

But I wonder if it would be possible to set up a volume, or an alternative solution, that:

- firstly cannot be edited on the host side,
- and secondly allows for the host directory contents to be *merged* with the container's directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if it would be possible to set up a volume, or an alternative solution, that
>
> firstly cannot be edited on the host side,

That would be a [data volume container (with `docker create` on an image with a `VOLUME` directive)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#data-volumes)

> and secondly allows for the host directory contents to be merged with the container's directory?

Not that I know of. [You would have to do some kind of copy on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27960880/6309).

Comment: That's what I suspected, I just needed some clarification - incase there was some sort of update that I wasn't aware of!