# Duplicate mount points

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to load multiple SQL files in the different folders to the database using volume mount in docker.

```
      - ../folder1:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - ../folder2:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I get the error:

ERROR: Duplicate mount points
Both the folders have tables in them so can not mount the folder2 to var lib.

How to resolve the error and mount data from folder1 first and then folder2

when i do:

```
      - ../folder1:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test1
      - ../folder2:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test2
```

Docker ignores them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge host folder with container folder in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959860/how-to-merge-host-folder-with-container-folder-in-docker)